# Which license to choose for PHP library for chargeable, patented work?

Tags: open-source, licensing

I have developed a PHP library which is a wrapper to our API.

**Patents:** The services rendered through the API are covered by patents and anyone using the library may be charged subject to usage crossing certain limits. The license must not grant anyone using the library any patent license.

**How Free?** Although the library is free, can be copied and distributed unmodified under the same name as much as it can be, usage will be charged depending on limits. In the event of non-payment, the services facilitated by the library will be disrupted.

**Modifications & Redistribution:** Although anyone is free to review, debug & modify the library, it is desired that modifications to the library are not released under the same name or seek to represent the original and intended library released by us.

**Included libraries:** The library we are providing uses PHPSecLib & SSS(Shamir's Secret Sharing) library by Kenny Millington. PHPSecLib is released under the MIT license & SSS is under GPLv3 or later.

In view of all this, which license should I choose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Patents:**

**How Free?**

A lot of API libraries are like that. The library is free but the service the API is utilizing isn't. See, for example, [Google AdWords API PHP Client](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-php/). It's Apache licensed which, in turn, is [GPL compatible](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#apache2).

**Modifications & Redistribution:**

That's a problem. The [PHP License](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html#PHP-3.01) has a similar restriction and as such it isn't GPL compatible. Of course if you don't care about GPL compatibility...

**Included libraries:**

The MIT license is pretty liberal and let's you do pretty much anything. GPLv3, however, is not. If you use GPLv3 code your license is going to need to be GPL compatible and with the restrictions you're wanting to impose it sounds like it's not going to be. My recommendation: maybe rewrite SSS? Compared to phpseclib it looks like an extremely small codebase.

Comment: This is helpful. I did home in on the Apachev2 License as the license to use but was worried about the "GPLv3 or later" clause in SSS. Anyhow, I will write an implementation of our own but the test suite may only delay things so that's why wanted to know if there is anything else possible. Thanks a lot.
And about modifications, we are doing this to prevent as much harm as can be by way of mis-representation of our services.

Comment: I have a question regarding license migration. Is it possible that I release the first beta version under GPLv3 and release the later stable versions under Apache2.0?

Comment: Yup. Apache2.0 wouldn't be retroactive so the GPLv3 code could still be modified while retaining the GPLv3. Pretty much, as the copyright holder, you can change the license to whatever you see fit (unless you're using other GPL code in your code). No one but you can change the license of your code but not even you can make retroactive changes.